# (Graphql) The resolver value isn't of type object

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server, graphql-js, express-graphql

I'm trying to use [anilist public api](https://graphql.anilist.co) while trying to set a backend using express and apollo, but I'm getting an error when I try to do a query using the ID of an anime to get some of its details. Any ideas on how to solve this?

**OBS: I got the query's example from the api website.**

```js
const {ApolloServer} = require("apollo-server-express");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const {gql} = require("apollo-server-express");

// Schema
let typeDefs = gql`
query { # Define which variables will be used in the query (id)
Media (id: $id, type: ANIME) { # Insert our variables into the query arguments (id) (type: ANIME is hard-coded in the query)
    id
    title {
      romaji
      english
      native
    }
  }
}
`;

// Resolver
let resolvers = {
    id: 15125
};


// Server
const server = new ApolloServer({typeDefs, resolvers});

// Define the config we'll need for our Api request
var url = 'https://graphql.anilist.co',
    options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            typeDefs: typeDefs,
            resolvers: resolvers
        })
    };

// Make the HTTP Api request
fetch(url, options).then(handleResponse)
                   .then(handleData)
                   .catch(handleError);

function handleResponse(response) {
    return response.json().then(function (json) {
        return response.ok ? json : Promise.reject(json);
    });
}

function handleData(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

function handleError(error) {
    alert('Error, check console');
    console.error(error);
}

// Apollo
async () => {
    await server.start();
    server.applyMiddleware({app});
};

// Express
app.get("/",(req,res) => res.send("Response from the GET request"));
//app.get("/graphql",(req,res) => res.send("Response from the GET request"));

app.listen({port: 4000}, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`);
});
```

The result of that is the following:

```js
throw new Error(`"${typeName}" defined in resolvers, but has invalid value "${resolverValue}". The resolver's value must be of type object.`);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Resolver
let resolvers = {
    id: 15125
};
```

change to this

```
// Resolver
const resolvers = {
   id : {"id" : 15125}
}
```

**id** is typeName, {"id" : 15125} this value object

Comment: So now how do I set this up in the schema? I got this error:
`Error: "getID" defined in resolvers, but not in schema`

Comment: @Kurokishin you can change to this
`// Resolver
const resolvers = {
    id : {"id" : 15125}
}`